# Definition question in algebraic topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

> **Definition**: The $p$th (de Rham) cohomology group is the quotient vector space $$H^p(U) = \frac{Ker(d:\Omega^{p}(U)\to \Omega^{p+1}(U)}{Im(d:\Omega^{p-1}(U)\to \Omega^{p}(U))}$$
>
> where $U \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, that is $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am wondering, because it says that $H^p(U) = 0$ for any $p <0$. So what happens if $p > n$ in the definition? For example, if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set, then what is $H^1(U)$? Is it also zero?

My book also states the **Mayer-Vietoris** as an exact sequence of cohomology quotient vector spaces,

$$\dots\to H^p(U) \to H^{p}(U_1) \oplus H^{p}(U_2) \to H^{p}(U_1 \cap U_2) \to H^{p+1}(U) \to \dots$$ where $U = U_1 \cup U_2 \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}$. Now does the "dot, dot, dot" imply it never ends in $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p>n$, then $H^p(U)=0$ since $\Omega^p(U)=0$ (for open $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$).

If $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set, then $H^1(U)$ depends on $U$ (but it is always finite dimensional and its dimension counts the number of "holes" in $U$, roughly speaking).

The $\dots$ just signifies that the sequence extends over all integer $p$. However, this doesn't imply that it never ends in $0$ - in fact, all but finitely many terms in this sequence are $0$ by the above reasoning. Also, you could have a sequence consisting *entirely* of $0$'s too if you choose $U$ and $V$ appropriately!

Let me know if you need clarification on any of these points and I would be very happy to do so!

Comment: So since $H^p(U) = 0$ if $p > n$, doesn't that mean the Mayer-Vietoris actually is a short exact sequence (only with the beginning and tail, the inside is never $0$ of course)?

Comment: Because the set $U$ is given (and fixed).

Comment: Dear @jip, a short exact sequence usually refers to a sequence of the form $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ (where none, some, or all of $A,B,C$ could be non-zero); this is simply a matter of terminology, though. In this terminology, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is not *short* exact in general, but it is an exact sequence so we refer to it as "long exact".

Answer (score 1):

The space $\Omega^p(U) = \Gamma(\bigwedge^p T^*U)$, and $\bigwedge^p T^*U = 0$ for $p > \dim T^*U = n$. Hence all such $\Omega^p(U)$ vanish. The Mayer-Vietoris sequence does eventually terminate in zero modules, but it's not a short exact sequence (in general); that term refers specifically to a three-term sequence $0 \to L \to M \to N \to 0$.

Comment: I know, but it "looks" like a short exact sequence is what I am trying to get at?

Comment: You can unwind the long exact sequence into a series of short exact sequences (I've seen this sometimes called d\'evissage, although the term is more often used in a different context), but it's not particularly useful without any further information about the maps. I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I want to know, for a given $U \subset \Bbb R^n$, whether the MV sequence is of the form $$0 \to H^0 \to \dots \to H^p \to 0$$?

Comment: Sure: Like I said, all the $H^p$ with $p > n$ vanish.